# How do I sort a group, in natural order, with letters and numbers in XSLT2?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have inherited code, where I'm not fully understanding why it's not working, but I also want it to do more.  The obvious issue is where the `group-by` is never going to find a group, because the attribute it's looking for is always a unique value for each item.  Beyond that, I am also looking for a natural order sort.  From what I can find, I think I may need to first sort the group by letters, and then sort that result by numbers, but I'm not sure.  Currently, even the basic sort that is there, isn't working.  The existing XSLT code is:

```xml
<xsl:for-each-group select="datafield[@tag='856']" group-by="subfield[@code='u']">
    <xsl:sort select="number(normalize-space(substring-after(subfield[@code='z'], ',')))"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Using this data:

```xml
<collection>
   <record>
      <datafield ind1="4" ind2="1" tag="856">
         <subfield code="u">https://www.example.com/ride02meys</subfield>
         <subfield code="z">Digital item, v.2</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield ind1="4" ind2="1" tag="856">
         <subfield code="u">https://www.example.com/ride01meys</subfield>
         <subfield code="z">Digital item, v.1</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield ind1="4" ind2="1" tag="856">
         <subfield code="u">https://www.example.com/ride12meys</subfield>
         <subfield code="z">Digital item, v.12</subfield>
   </record>
</collection>
```

I'm trying to get the following, where it's sorted as 1, 2, 12, and not 1, 12, 2.

```xml
<collection>
   <record>
      <datafield ind1="4" ind2="1" tag="856">
         <subfield code="u">https://www.example.com/ride01meys</subfield>
         <subfield code="z">Digital item, v.1</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield ind1="4" ind2="1" tag="856">
         <subfield code="u">https://www.example.com/ride02meys</subfield>
         <subfield code="z">Digital item, v.2</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield ind1="4" ind2="1" tag="856">
         <subfield code="u">https://www.example.com/ride12meys</subfield>
         <subfield code="z">Digital item, v.12</subfield>
   </record>
</collection>
```

I'm admittedly weak with XSLT, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort your data first alphanumerically by the string before the dot and then numerically by the string after the dot you can use two `xsl:sort`s like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="datafield[@tag='856']" group-by="subfield[@code='u']">
    <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring-before(subfield[@code='z'],'.'))" data-type="text"  order="ascending" />
    <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring-after(subfield[@code='z'], '.'))" data-type="number" order="ascending" />            
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This assumes that the dot `.` can be used as a delimiter. If the delimiter varies, this approach couldn't be used.

*As a side note:*
the `group-by="subfield[@code='u']"` of the `xsl:for-each-group` has the effect that only the first of each `subfield` with an identical value is processed. If you need all `subfield`s, either iterate over the `current-group()` with `xsl:for-each` or use `xsl:for-each` in the first place.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  The only catch, is that it's not always "v.".  That field varies quite a bit, sometimes being years, or the "v.", being "vol." instead.  But if it was at least sorted alphabetically, and then numerically, it would be a great help.  Thanks again for the `group-by` info.

Comment: This solution only works for the specific case where the sort key consists of an alphabetic part followed by a dot followed by a numeric part. It's not going to work, for example, for a key like "Volume 23 Issue 3".

Comment: @MichaelKay - While I chose cleaned up examples, to put it mildly, the data I'm working with, is highly inconsistent.  So, even though I'm painfully aware of exactly how right you are, any semblance of a sort, is still a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `collation` like `http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?lang=en;numeric=yes` on the `xsl:sort`, as in

```
 <xsl:template match="record">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="datafield[@tag='856']" group-by="subfield[@code='u']">
            <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring-after(subfield[@code='z'], ','))"
               collation="http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?lang=en;numeric=yes"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>          
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nt

Read more about collations at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#uca-collations.

For older Saxon 9 versions you can use a different collation:

```
  <xsl:template match="record">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="datafield[@tag='856']" group-by="subfield[@code='u']">
            <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(substring-after(subfield[@code='z'], ','))"
               collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?lang=en;alphanumeric=yes"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>          
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/nbiCsZq has an example, documentation is at http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/extensibility/config-extend/collation/implementing-collation.html.

Comment: Note that this UCA collation URI is standardised in XSLT 3.0, so it should be offered by all XSLT 3.0 processors. Collation URIs are available in XSLT 2.0, but they aren't standardised across different processors.